# Hosting MVVMLight WPF app in WindowsForms

Tags: wpf, winforms, mvvm-light

Is it possible to host an MVVMLight WPF application's windows in Windows Forms? What would be the proper bootstrapping procedure?

**UPDATE:**

By looking at what's inside InitializeComponent of App.xaml, I was able to bootstrap MVVMLight like so:

in Program.cs

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var wpfApp = new WpfApp();
        Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/AssemblyName;component/app.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(wpfApp, resourceLocater);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Then, in my on-click event handler, to show MainControl WPF UserControl I can use:

```
var window = new MainControl();
var form = new Form(){MdiParent = this};
form.Controls.Add( new ElementHost(){Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Child = window } );
form.Show();
```

If no one has better idea, I will accept this as an answer in a couple of days.

Comment: You can host `WPF` control in `WinForm` form or control. Look at the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Hamlet, I knew that much and am looking for the proper way to bootstrap the creation of models, resource locators, etc., specifically for MVVMLight Toolkit or Caliburn.Micro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var wpfApp = new WpfApp();
    Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/AssemblyName;component/app.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
    System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(wpfApp, resourceLocater);

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```